# Ruby profiler extra methods calls resulted

Tags: ruby, methods, profiler

I was playing today with Ruby profiler and found something strange in my results. Let's take a sample code from docs:

```
require 'profile'

def slow_method
  5000.times do
    9999999999999999*999999999
  end
end

def fast_method
  5000.times do
    9999999999999999+999999999
  end
end

slow_method
fast_method
```

Results of methods calls should look like:

```
0.00     0.19      0.00        1     0.00   100.00  Object#slow_method
0.00     0.19      0.00        1     0.00    90.00  Object#fast_method
```

But my results are:

```
35.00     0.15      0.07     5001     0.01     0.03  Object#fast_method
10.00     0.19      0.02     5001     0.00     0.03  Object#slow_method
```

And it doesn't seem to be proper. Those methods are called once, not 5001 times.

Btw. I'm using **ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]**

Comment: That's very likely a 2.x specific bug (related to `TracePoint`?) since it works as expected with 1.9.3.

Comment: Or an [intentional change](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/9ed4d1ab8ca3bcf10cd57144768176235a06dbf4)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My questions are: 
1. Is this happening only to me or other rubyist too?
2. And if to others also, is this some change because of 2.x(as @cremno pointed out)? Because on other versions it works fine to me.
Just looking for origin of these differences.

Comment: Yes, it can be reproduced but only with 2.x because of that linked commit. You could report it as a bug [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk) and ask for the rationale behind this change and mistakes in the documentation are bugs anyway. So don't worry.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll report that.